# Entity Framework 6 generates tables in database - but I don't want them

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I use ASP.NET MVC 5, Entity Framework 6. I use database-first methodology. I created database and then ASP.NET MVC application but Entity Framework adds tables to my database, for example: `_Migrationhistory`, `People` (I have my own table `Person` in database).

This is my context in application:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
        public DatabaseContext() : base("DatabaseContext") { }

        public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

What is going on?

Comment: what is the connection string you are using? is it named "DatabaseContext" in your configuration file?

Answer (score 3):

EF creates the tables by default, unless you explicitly tell it not to. More about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679461%28v=vs.113%29.aspx).

You can disable the Initializer using the following code:

```
Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(null);
```

**Sample usage:**

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    // This static constructor disables the initializer.
    static DatabaseContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(null);
    }

    public DatabaseContext() : base("DatabaseContext") { }

    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Note the `_Migrationhistory` table is required if you want to use the [database migration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx) feature..

Comment: The OP is on a different workflow. And the _MigrationHistory is always created whenever they decide to fallback to migration.